# Scientific texture analysis

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing, scripting

i'm very new to Blender, so i would like to ask about the feasibility of the following:

I have 200 images of a sphere of a process over time. 100 images are camera recordings from the front of the sphere and 100 are from the back. I want to model the sphere and implement an animation with the 200 images applied on the surface of the sphere. 
This will result in a sphere animation where over time a bright/white spot expands radially over the sphere until the whole sphere is white.

Is it possible with Blender to analyse the surface changes i.e. measure how much the white area is expanding?

If yes, do i need additional plugins/scripts? If yes, what are those?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do you need to actually model your signal? Or do you just need to project your images onto the surface of a sphere?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just calculate the change in surface area mathematically, ie projecting circle on surface of another and compare the areas?

There are couple of approaches you could take, they are approximations depending on the resolution of your image files of course. You could unwrap and texture bake white dots on a black sphere and compare the amount of white in the image pixels that constitute the surface. Or wrap on top of sphere, add huge amount of subdivision and measure the area of white polygons, possibly using displace modifier to identify illuminated polygons by code.

Comment: @ajwood: you're right, i just need to project the images on the sphere. From there on i was hoping for a script/function to do something like 'kheetor' suggests. In the end i want to calculate the velocity of the radially expanding white area. Think of circles getting bigger over the sphere.

Comment: Do you know how to UV-Unwrap (project from view) and create a Cycles material with an image sequence?  If not, I can add an answer with that much to get you started.

Comment: No, i don't. That would be very helpful ajwood! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't help you analyze your texture, but it'll at least get you projecting it on the sphere.

1. Add a UV-Sphere to your scene
   [image]
2. Switch to front-view (<kbd>1</kbd>) and set camera view <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>
   [image]
3. In edit mode, use box-select (<kbd>B</kbd>) to select the vertices visible from the front, then UV-Unwrap, selecting "Project From View"
   [image]
4. In the UV/Image Editor window with your vertices still selected, open one of your images and scale the UV-unwrapped mesh to fit
   [image]
5. Add a material to your sphere, using your image sequence
   [image]
6. Switch to rendered view, and see your image projected onto the sphere
   [image]

Comment: I glossed over a fair bit of stuff.. let me know if you need more detailed instructions for using the interface.

Comment: Thanks ajwood! i will do as you laid out and i will get back if i know more about analysis. best wishes!